# SQL Report builder: split data between primary and secondary axis

Tags: reportbuilder

I have a table which contains Date (DateTime), Value (integer), and TagID (integer).

The TagID refers to the ID of some transmitters that send me data (the current date and time and a numeric value retrieved from a sensor) every n seconds; this data is stored in the table I described before.

I need to create a chart to compare the data of two of these transmitters, but I encountered a problem. The numeric values of one transmitter is usually under 100, while the other is well over 100000, so if I just put them together on the same scale, the first one is unreadable.

Can I scale the data of the second transmitter using the secondary axis? How?

Answer (score 0):

You can select then right click on the horizontal axis on your chart, open Properties and on the Axis Options tab there are two things that can work for you:

- Axis range and interval: if you have a set minimum, maximum and interval values
- Under scale options, you can turn on logarithmic scale if that's more fitting

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the one I'm doing this thing for doesn't want a logarithmic scale, so I must find some other workaround.

Comment: What if you divide your other values in your query by let's say a 1000?

Comment: That's probably the closest thing I can think of, so I'll do that for now, but I'd really like to have those two scales.